# Understanding xml markup while using pandas.read_xml()

Tags: python, pandas, xml, readxml

Have never tried parsing xml markup for data extraction hitherto. And now I've got the task to extract data from the statistical source.
My naïve approach is to rely solely on **pandas.read_xml()** as per below:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
pd.options.display.max_columns = 8


URL = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=g17&filetype=zip"
r = requests.get(URL)
with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)) as z:
    # =========================================================================
    # Select the Largest File Containing the Most of the Data
    # =========================================================================
    _map = {_.file_size: _.filename for _ in z.filelist}
    with z.open(_map[max(_map)]) as f:
        df = pd.read_xml(f)
        print(df)
```

Within **pd.read_xml(f)**, there is the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>  <message:MessageGroup xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message"  xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/common"  xmlns:frb="http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/common"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message SDMXMessage.xsd http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/common frb_common.xsd"><message:Header xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v1_0/message">
    <message:ID>G17</message:ID>
    <message:Test>false</message:Test>
    <message:Name>G.17 - Industrial Production and Capacity Utilization</message:Name>
    <message:Prepared>2022-07-15T00:38:22</message:Prepared>
    <message:Sender id="FRB">
      <message:Name>Federal Reserve Board</message:Name>
      <message:Contact>
        <message:Name>Public Affairs</message:Name>
        <message:Telephone>(202) 452 - 3204</message:Telephone>
      </message:Contact>
    </message:Sender>
  </message:Header>
<frb:DataSet id="IP_MAJOR_INDUSTRY_GROUPS" xmlns:kf="http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/G17_IP_MAJOR_INDUSTRY_GROUPS" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compact/G17_IP_MAJOR_INDUSTRY_GROUPS G17_IP_MAJOR_INDUSTRY_GROUPS.xsd"  > 
<kf:Series CURRENCY="NA" FREQ="129" SA="SA" SERIES_CODE="B50001" SERIES_NAME="IP.B50001.S" UNIT="Index:_2017_100" UNIT_MULT="1"  > 
<frb:Annotations>
<common:Annotation>
<common:AnnotationType>Short Description</common:AnnotationType>
<common:AnnotationText>Total index; s.a. IP</common:AnnotationText>
</common:Annotation>
<common:Annotation>
<common:AnnotationType>Long Description</common:AnnotationType>
<common:AnnotationText>Total index; s.a. IP</common:AnnotationText>
</common:Annotation>
</frb:Annotations>
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.8773" TIME_PERIOD="1919-01-31" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.6617" TIME_PERIOD="1919-02-28" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.5270" TIME_PERIOD="1919-03-31" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.6078" TIME_PERIOD="1919-04-30" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="4.6348" TIME_PERIOD="1919-05-31" />
... Skip ...

<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="102.9981" TIME_PERIOD="2022-02-28" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="103.7286" TIME_PERIOD="2022-03-31" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="104.5224" TIME_PERIOD="2022-04-30" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="104.5729" TIME_PERIOD="2022-05-31" />
<frb:Obs OBS_STATUS="A" OBS_VALUE="104.3648" TIME_PERIOD="2022-06-30" />
</kf:Series>
... Many More Lines Omitted To the End of the Document ...
```

Desirable output for the shown sample would be:

```
TIME_PERIOD IP.B50001.S
1919-01-31     4.8773
1919-02-28     4.6617
1919-03-31     4.5270
1919-04-30     4.6078
1919-05-31     4.6348
... Skip ...

2022-02-28   102.9981
2022-03-31   103.7286
2022-04-30   104.5224
2022-05-31   104.5729
2022-06-30   104.3648
```

For the moment, it doesn't return the desirable result as the whole target data seems to be omitted.
The output I get is:

```
      ID   Test                                               Name  \
0    G17  false  G.17 - Industrial Production and Capacity Util...   
1   None   None                                               None   
2   None   None                                               None   
3   None   None                                               None   
4   None   None                                               None   
5   None   None                                               None   
6   None   None                                               None   
7   None   None                                               None   
8   None   None                                               None   
9   None   None                                               None   
10  None   None                                               None   
11  None   None                                               None   
12  None   None                                               None   
13  None   None                                               None   
14  None   None                                               None   

               Prepared  Sender                                      id  \
0   2022-07-15T00:38:22     NaN                                    None   
1                  None     NaN                IP_MAJOR_INDUSTRY_GROUPS   
2                  None     NaN                 IP_DURABLE_GOODS_DETAIL   
3                  None     NaN              IP_NONDURABLE_GOODS_DETAIL   
4                  None     NaN            IP_MINING_AND_UTILITY_DETAIL   
5                  None     NaN                        IP_MARKET_GROUPS   
6                  None     NaN                   IP_SPECIAL_AGGREGATES   
7                  None     NaN  IP_GROSS_VALUE_STAGE_OF_PROCESS_GROUPS   
8                  None     NaN                                     MVA   
9                  None     NaN                                    DIFF   
10                 None     NaN                                     CAP   
11                 None     NaN                                  CAPUTL   
12                 None     NaN                                    GVIP   
13                 None     NaN                                     RIW   
14                 None     NaN                                      KW   

                                       schemaLocation  Series  
0                                                None     NaN  
1   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
2   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
3   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
4   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
5   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
6   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
7   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
8   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
9   http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
10  http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
11  http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
12  http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
13  http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN  
14  http://www.federalreserve.gov/structure/compac...     NaN
```

That looks more like the table of contents rather than the target data itself.

Currently, the task breaks up two-fold:

- What kwargs shall I pass to **pandas.read_xml()** to get more meaningful data?
- If the more meaningful data is retrieved successfully, the next step would be to make use of the auxilliary files within the zip-archive (say, the file <**G17_IP_MAJOR_INDUSTRY_GROUPS.xsd**>) to assign the column names if the output of the first step is not much human readable.

Thank you!

Comment: do you know how your xlm looks like and which data exactly do you want to extract? 
You can pass a `xpath` parameter to get the data that you want or you can first explore the xml file with a python xml parser (e.g. xml.etree.ElementTree or defusedexpat) and then pass the data to pandas in the schema that you need

Comment: thank you for reaching out! at this point of time, obviously not the best one :-), I honestly neither see the structure of the data nor prepared enough to work it with the stack like xml.etree.ElementTree. shall try your suggestion out unless any community member may bring up or point at some other powerful tool for the purpose

Comment: It may make it easier for people to help you if you edit your question, show a **short, representative** sample of your `(f)` xml file and the expected output based on that sample.

Comment: Thank you for the input! Updated the question to show up the samples. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your sample xml, but assuming it's fixed the way I believe it's supposed to be (it's too long to paste here), then `read_xml()` is probably unable to parse it so that your expected output is generated.

Instead I would go through lxml first and then pass the output of certain xpath expressions (see below) to pandas to create the dataframe:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(f)
doc = tree.getroot()

#your expected columns:
cols = ["TIME_PERIOD", "IP.B50001.S"]

#the base xpath expression
expr = '//*[local-name()="Obs"]'
rows = []
for r in doc.xpath(expr):
    row = []

    #use more xpath expressions to get to the target attributes
    row.extend([r.xpath('.//@TIME_PERIOD')[0], r.xpath('.//@OBS_VALUE')[0]])
    rows.append(row)
frdf = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
frdf
```

Output:

```
    TIME_PERIOD     IP.B50001.S
0   1919-01-31  4.8773
1   1919-02-28  4.6617
2   1919-03-31  4.5270
```

etc.